# htaccess broken another page url to remove userprofile.php?user=

Tags: .htaccess

I have 2 page link:

1. www.myweb.com/userprofile.php?user=username
2. www.myweb.com/gallery.php?user=username

Now I am going to hide 1st page `userprofile.php?user=` form url by adding below htaccess rule, which work well, but its broken also `gallery.php?user=username` url link and display a blank page.

After adding below htaccess rule 2nd page url broken and display: `www.myweb.com/gallery/?user=username`

> I want my pages will be:
>
> 1. www.myweb.com/username
> 2. www.myweb.com/gallery.php?user=username

Here is `htaccess rules`:

```
# Remove userprofile.php?user= #
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ userprofile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]


# Remove .php extension #
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: For gallery you should keep `www.myweb.com/g/username` pretty URL

Comment: Glad to see you sir. Ok, I am trying .

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you for give me suggest about www.myweb.com/g/username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep this code in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# for userprofile
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ userprofile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

# for gallery
RewriteRule ^g/([\w-]+)/?$ gallery.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Its show folder `/g/` that means `www.myweb.com/g/username` in all tab of gallery page. My gallery page tab link as: `<a href="../main.php"> Main </a>`

Comment: Gallery rule is a proposal because `www.myweb.com/username` cannot be routed to both `userprofile.php` and `gallery.php`